# Why are val_accuracy automatically printed by model.fit() after each epoch and accuracy printed by CustomCallback different?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Why the difference between - loss: 0.2105 - accuracy: 0.9500 - val_loss: 0.5264 - ***val_accuracy: 0.9100***

and

***accuracy:0.700*** printed in CustomCallback?

I'm pretty sure that CustomCallback's val_accuracy is correct.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wiy46.png

```
Callbacks =[
    checkpoint_callback(start_time),
    CustomCallback(val_ds, result, files_path, class_names,start_time)]
```

```
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=40, verbose = 1, callbacks=Callbacks,validation_data=val_ds,steps_per_epoch=20)
```

below is the CustomCallback which will count and print accuracy, leakage, and overkill

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, val_ds, result, files_path, class_names,start_time):
        super(CustomCallback, self).__init__()
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.val_ds = val_ds
        self.result = result
        self.files_path = files_path
        self.class_names = class_names
    
    def get_map(self, pred_valid, epoch):

        overkill_count = 0
        leakage_count = 0
        good_count = 0
        bad_count = 0
        same = 0
        for i ,f in enumerate(self.files_path):
            pred = self.class_names[np.argmax(pred_valid[i])]
            label = self.result[f]['label']
            
            if pred == label :
                same += 1
                
            if label == 'good':
            
                good_count = good_count + 1
                
                if pred != 'good':
                    overkill_count = overkill_count + 1
                    
            else:
                bad_count = bad_count + 1
                if pred == 'good':
                    leakage_count = leakage_count + 1
                    
        print(".\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n")
        print("epoch: ", epoch+1)
        print("total: ",good_count+bad_count)
        print("accuracy: ", same/(good_count+bad_count))
        print("good count: ", good_count)
        print("bad count: ", bad_count)
        
        print("overkill count: ", overkill_count)
        print("leakage count: ", leakage_count)
        
        overkill_rate = overkill_count / good_count
        leakage_rate = leakage_count / bad_count
        
        print("overkill_rate: ", overkill_rate)
        print("leakage_rate: ", leakage_rate)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        model_test = self.model
        for layer in model_test.layers:
            layer.trainable = False
        print("model predicting.....")
        pred_valid = model_test.predict(self.val_ds)
        print("model predict done.")
        self.get_map(pred_valid, epoch)
        print("totally spends {:1f} minutes.".format((time.time()-self.start_time)/60))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed 2 datasets, the training dataset, and the validation dataset
The model fits on the training dataset, and does not see anything from the validation dataset. After each epoch, the model evaluates on the validation dataset and thus giving you a total of 4 metrics
And after each epoch, `loss` is the loss from the training dataset, and `accuracy` is the accuracy metric of the training dataset.
`val_loss` is the loss from validation dataset, and `val_accuracy` is the accuracy from the validation dataset.
`val_loss` and `val_accuracy` is printed out so that you can compare it to the training `loss` and `accuracy` and determine if your model is overfitting to the training dataset or not.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed replied.
However, my question is why the val_accuracy you mentioned is different from the val_accuracy calculated from my CustonCallback?

Comment: Your `CustomCallback` is not the same as the keras default `accuracy` metric. That's why

Comment: But both ```CustomCallback```  and ```Keras default accuracy``` are using the same model to predict the same validation_data, how come the predict result being different?
Or, how can I fix my ```CustomCallback```?

Comment: The metrics are not same. Just like `mse` & `mae` loss functions give different outputs (for the same model & same data), your `CustomCallback` is different from the default keras `accuracy` metric as so gives different outputs from the same model & same data

Comment: As far as I know, ```metric``` in model.fit() is a parameter for training. Now I'm in evaluation stage, I don't think ```metric``` involves in this stage.